# Can't fade in my navbar when fixing it to the top with jquery

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery to fix my navbar at the top on scrolldown, the `sticky` class takes care of that. However, I want the browser to do it smoothly, like a quick fade In. Can I use `fadeIn` before adding the class? So far, it hasn't worked.

```
var num = 1; //number of pixels before modifying styles
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.navbar') fadeIn(500).addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

Comment: could you make jsFiddle?

Comment: Use a CSS-opacity-transition at the sticky-class

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `.` in this statement

```
 $('.navbar')fadeIn(500).addClass('sticky');
```

It should be

```
 $('.navbar').fadeIn(500).addClass('sticky');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a transition to your .navbar CSS:

```
.navbar {
    ...
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

**Note:** The property to animate, must always be set - even before the scrolling...

Here a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ky3916tn/1/

Comment: Why not? Just make sure the property that should be animated is always set (also before scrolling).

(edited my answer with a working example)